# Quartz cron trigger for every 2 weeks and 2 times a day ( 6 AM and 6PM)

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, batch-processing, cronexpression

I want to run a quartz job for every 2 weeks at morning 6'o clock and evening 6'o clock . how to achieve this .please advice.

I tried to schedule using below cron expression

```
01 01 1 1-0/14 01 ? *
```

but the next fire times are as below.

> 1. Sunday, January 1, 2017 1:01 AM
> 2. Sunday, January 15, 2017 1:01 AM
> 3. Sunday, January 29, 2017 1:01 AM
> 4. Monday, January 1, 2018 1:01 AM
> 5. Monday, January 15, 2018 1:01 AM

Comment: Maybe explain what you want the next fire times to be, because I'm not sure if I understand the question clearly. You want it to fire at 6am and 6pm, twelve hours apart, but then not again for another 14 days, and then again twice in short succession?

Comment: updated the cron expression 01 01 6,18 1-0/14 01 ? * . the next fire times are shown as below                                                                                          1. Sunday, January 1, 2017 6:01 AM
2. Sunday, January 1, 2017 6:01 PM
3. Sunday, January 15, 2017 6:01 AM
4. Sunday, January 15, 2017 6:01 PM
5. Sunday, January 29, 2017 6:01 AM
6. Sunday, January 29, 2017 6:01 PM
7. Monday, January 1, 2018 6:01 AM
8. Monday, January 1, 2018 6:01 PM
9. Monday, January 15, 2018 6:01 AM
10. Monday, January 15, 2018 6:01 PM

Comment: What I /want/ to know is what fire time you want the expression to generate so that I'm sure I'm giving you the right revised expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some kinds of date triggers cron is good at. Every N days is often not one of them. For instance, if you use something like this:

```
0 0 6,18 */14 * ?
```

You might get something like this:

1. Tuesday, March 29, 2016 6:00 AM
2. Tuesday, March 29, 2016 6:00 PM
3. Friday, April 1, 2016 6:00 AM
4. Friday, April 1, 2016 6:00 PM
5. Friday, April 15, 2016 6:00 AM
6. Friday, April 15, 2016 6:00 PM

As you can see, the 29th, followed by the 1st -- not exactly fourteen days apart.

It's useful to have something that lets you play with the expression and see the resulting dates. [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com) can do that, if that's helpful.

However, since you say you are using Quartz, it supports other kinds of triggers, like `DateIntervalTrigger` that might be better suited for what you're looking for?

Comment: Ah, right. Unfortunately, cron is great at expressing some kinds of schedules and not so great at other kinds of schedules. When you get past a certain point, you start doing things like just invoking a script every day and having that script decide if it should be invoked (every 14 days). It's not great, but cron just doesn't support every desired schedule.